# Fetching all the monday dates (only) for the past 4 weeks?

Tags: excel, date

I'm working on an excel report where I need the dates of the past 4 Mondays from the current dates. so for example, today's march 28th, I need to get the 4 dates Feb 28, March 7,14, 21.

Is there any way for me to do this formula on excel? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Excel-365 you may try-

```
=TEXT(FILTER(SEQUENCE(28,1,TODAY()-1,-1),TEXT(SEQUENCE(28,1,TODAY()-1,-1),"dddd")="Monday"),"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun, thanks so much for you reply! It works but what do I place on the next rows? If I use the code that you've mentioned it only returns Mar 21st. Do I need to add a plus one somewhere?

Comment: solved, I've used : =TEXT(FILTER(SEQUENCE(28,1,TODAY()-2,-2),TEXT(SEQUENCE(28,1,TODAY()-1,-1),"dddd")="Monday"),"dd-mmm-yyyy") and just changed -2 to -3 and so on

Comment: @Rokugatsu29 If your version support dynamic array approach then you no need to enter anything else. It will automatically spill all the results.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not too familiar with support dynamic array approach.. I added the formula that you've mentioned but they only show one date : March 28th so I was wondering what can I do to the formula if I place them on the other columns similar with what you have on your screenshot. thank you!